# Trying to define method that makes datetime entries by day of week

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a datetime column in one of my tables (team_opps) called start_date.

I am trying to write methods in my model that allow me to classify them as Monday, Tuesday, etc... opportunities.

```
  def self.friday_team_opps
    where('WEEKDAY(start_date) = ?', 4)
  end
```

In my view I am trying to call a .each on it.

```
  <% TeamOpp.friday_team_opps.each do |team_opp| %>
     <%= render team_opp, :team_opp => :team_opp %>
  <% end %>
```

Error is:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: WEEKDAY: SELECT "team_opps".* FROM "team_opps"  WHERE (WEEKDAY(start_date) = 4)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to define the method on the TeamOpp class by defining the method as `def self.friday_team_opps`.

Moreover, you can't call methods on the column since it would require ActiveRecord to load all the data in your table and then call the Ruby method on that data. What you can do is use direct SQL functions, like for example MySQL's [WEEKDAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) (monday = 0, tuesday = 1, etc.):

```
def self.friday_team_opps
  where("WEEKDAY(team_opps.created_at) = ?", 4)
end
```

In SQLite, you can use the [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function (sunday = 0, monday = 1, etc.):

```
def self.friday_team_opps
  where('strftime("%w", "created_at") = "?"', 5)
end
```

Comment: I updated my code above to show what I have now, which is what you suggested.  THe error i'm running into now is :SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: WEEKDAY: SELECT "team_opps".* FROM "team_opps"  WHERE (WEEKDAY(team_opps.start_date) = 4)

Comment: use this :
def self.friday_team_opps
  where('WEEKDAY(created_at) = ?', 4)
end

Comment: same error.  i love this approach though.  still doesn't like the weekday function.

Comment: Unfortunately, these SQL functions are vendor specific, I've updated the answer with a solution for SQLite ;)

Comment: Thank you - works great!  Is it best practice to have my view the way it is?  I have enough methods in my model that I do not need an instance variable in the controller.

Comment: It looks fine, even though the MVC paradigm dictates that views should never access the models directly. In addition, I don't think you actually need the `:team_opp => :team_opp`.

Comment: Thanks - is there a reason this would not work in a PG database environment?  It works fine in localhost but on heroku it gives the error 'ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "%w" does not exist'

Comment: Postgres has yet another set of functions, so yeah it's normal :)

Answer (score 0):

You define it as an instance method

```
def friday_team_opps
```

And it should be defined as a class method

```
def self.friday_team_opps
```

Comment: Does this change what's inside the method itself?

Comment: self.will reference the model itself. In you case - `TeamOpp`. That's what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it a instance function then you should use it like this

```
def friday_team_opps
    return self.start_date.strftime("%A")
end
```

Subsequently you will have to modify your view like this :

```
<% TeamOpp.select("start_date").each do |team_opp| %>
     <%= team_opp.friday_team_opps() %>
<% end %>
```